# Is there anyway to set version control on ALM to sync with Gitlab?

Tags: version-control, gitlab, alm

I have read how to use version control on ALM from [Source](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/online_help/Content/UG/t_use_versioning.htm). However, i really want to use ALM to sync with Gitlab. Is there anyway we can set/use script to do check-in or check-out directly through Gitlab ?.
If it is possible, please share any idea/source/document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Entities do you want to checkout? Test, Components, etc? You could checkout through the COM OTA API.

Comment: @Jonas  Thanks for your help . I already solve this  by let alm read on the target folder on my pc which already set Git CMD. Anyway , Could you provide documentation for COM OTA API ?.

Comment: for sure. The OTA provides very good extensibility for us, we have several tools developed using the ota. You should install Visual Studio and just add an reference to the Otaclient.dll (typical in %appdata%/Local/HP/ALM-Client/<Version>/OTAClient.dll)
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/api_refs/ota/Default.htm